# what is the Order thru which dns name is resolved for any web application?

Tags: dns

I have java based application hosted on my local tomcat server.As per my understanding whenever I type http://us.states.com/myApplication. There is a order browser will try to resolve the DNS name us.states.com. I.e

1. First it will look for us.states.com in hosts file
2. Secondly it will look for us.states.com on local DNS server (if it is there)
3. Last it will look for us.states.com on web (with appending of www in front of us.states.com)

Is that correct?

Comment: Depends on client-side settings and operating system. There is no "one way a client resolved a DNS name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two are correct, the third is not. If it appends www-or not is normally a redirect issue. Hence, DNS name resolving will only be against either local host file or against one or more DNS servers.

Answer (score 1):

One and two are correct. First the hosts file is checked, then your DNS server. There is no 3.

Also, step 2 is not necessarily a DNS server local to your network. It can be specified on your machine (separately from DHCP) or it can be specified by the network. Usually the DNS server is on a machine owned by your ISP, unless you explicitly use a different one. For example I sometimes use Google's public DNS servers (8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4) or Level3's (4.2.2.1 through 4.2.2.7 or so).